# TimeoutError when connecting aws postgres instance thru nodeJS

Tags: postgresql, timeout, amazon-rds

Database connects successfully when connecting via

1. pgadmin
2. psql

But causing *TimeoutError: query timed out* while connecting it using sequelize/pg from nodeJS

sequelize approach followed is as shown below,

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PWD, {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  logging: process.env.DB_SHOW_LOGS === 'true',
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },
});
```

Any insight ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by upgrading 'pg' module to 8.5.1 !!!